# Is there a native .NET component that is analogous to the StringGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, tstringgrid

I need a control like a StringGrid (a multi-celled grid or table-like control (spreadsheet, matrix, whatever). Is there something that can be used as such in .NET?

Comment: Which GUI platform? WinForms? WPF? ASP.net?

Comment: You do have to make an effort to not find the three grid controls built into .NET

Comment: @Hans and Yorye: This is not for data per se, that's why I'm not considering DataGridView (which I use elsewhere). I need something more like StringGrid, where I specify the number of cols and rows (they are fixed) and then populate _some_ of the cells with data from a DB.

Comment: @Melllvar: I tagged the question as Winforms

Comment: I'm guessing you think DGV is only appropriate for data.  That's incorrect, works fine on strings with a fixed number of rows and columns as well.

Comment: `ListView` is a possibility, as well.

Comment: Hi, Jim; I was just going to post that (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx) Are you still in Austin, TX?

Comment: @Hans: So, now I wonder which is better for my purposes, DGV or LV. For now, I'm leaning toward LV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DatagridView is better option.

Comment: Hi clay, what i  get from your question is that u wanna  populate specified row n col from database. U can have dataset where u can put one table n inside this table have all ur data from DB.assign this dataset to DGV.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit, using the arguments in your comment? _DatagridView is better option._ is not really an answer.

Comment: @Prateek: No, only one third of the "cells" will have data from a database; two-thirds are constant strings (placeholders/labels). I'm going to dynamically create controls and put them on a panel instead.